# Use Memcache class with binary protocol

Tags: php, memcached

Has someone succesfully set up a connection with Memcached by the binary protocol through the Memcache client class? And by connection I mean to connect to the server, to set an arbitrary key and then retrieve this key.

I've found problems trying to get keys from Memcached through the binary protocol with this class. It seems that Memcached is closing the connection unexpectedly, so then PHP throws a notice.

This is some example code that lead me to this issue

```php
ini_set('memcache.protocol', 'binary');
$m = new Memcache();
$m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$m->set('test', 'test');
echo $m->get('test');
```

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Chances are memcache works for most people, at least its developers. Why don't you post the precise error (and a [short](http://sscce.org/) example program demonstrating it) and as much as much info as possible about your setup (Firewall, OS, memcached/php version, etc.)?

Comment: yes, adding a code to your question will bring you chance to get proper solution here on QA StackOverflow :)

Comment: Also I have to add that this code was tested with the Memcache 3.0.6 beta version (the last version released).